# How can I checkout the OpenJDK from the mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, repository, checkout, java

How can I checkout the the sources of the OpenJDK? I want see if some bug fixes work. The last download is very old. I use the the mercurial URL http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6. But I see only a revision of 58 and some make files in the repository. It does not look like the sources of the OpenJDK.

Is this the wrong repository URL? It is list on the project home page at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/.

I have never work with mercurial before. What am I doingg wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/

The URL you had is for the top-level folder that encompases a number of jdk-related repositories. (For a list of all of the repos, see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/ )