# How to clone the OpenJDK Java 8 repository?

Tags: mercurial, java

How do I clone the OpenJDK repository using mercurial?

I would like to clone the Java source code from there to understand what they are developing in JDK8 and would like to co-operate if possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The repository is linked on http://openjdk.java.net/. Clone it and execute the`get_source.sh` script.

```
$ hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8
$ cd jdk8 && sh get_source.sh
```

A [guide to the OpenJDK repositories](http://openjdk.java.net/guide/repositories.html) and a [How to contribute](http://openjdk.java.net/contribute/) are available, too.

Answer (score 4):

**Have a look [at the README](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/file/1773f1fd0fac/README)** of the version you want to clone.

After doing what [another answer said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457107/how-to-clone-the-openjdk-java-8-repository/27771044#27771044):

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8
```

you also need to run:

```
sh get_source.sh
```

to actually clone most of the source code, which is split into multiple sub-repositories.

Related: [How can I checkout the OpenJDK from the mercurial repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121922/how-can-i-checkout-the-openjdk-from-the-mercurial-repository)